# How to create this diagram with Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm fairly familiar with using Tikz. I've used it to make simple logos before. Now, I'd like to create this diagram, which is a little more complicated:

[image]

Does anyone have any advice on what the best way to do this would be?

I'm aware that it's very easy to use the image file in my output (\includegraphics). However, I'd like to make it in Tikz if possible, for infinite scalability.

BTW, the blue is #080f6a.

Comment: When you really want that to have in Ti*k*Z  you can actually let e.g `inkscape` to redraw the logo and produce a Ti*k*Z output.

Comment: In addition to current_user's comment, you would get the same scalability with any vector graphics format/software.

Comment: In addition to the methods described above, since this picture has just two colors you may convert it to the `pnm` format, from there with `potrace` to eps, which will make it a *vector* graphics, i.e. scalable, and then to pdf. I just tried that out and this also gives a very smooth and of course scalable picture.

Comment: @Sebastiano Somehow I don't feel that that is a good duplicate. The question you link is about turning pictures of math formulae into TeX code. This question on the other hand asks to convert a bitmap image to TikZ (or at least a vector format).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The short answer is that, yes, this is possible *but* I have to warn you that questions of the form "Please draw this for me" that show no effort on the part of OP, often don't get answered. You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). A quick search on TeX.SX for drawing functions (with tikz or pstricks) will give you an idea of where to start from.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for the comment. I didn't include an MWE, because I didn't think the answers would require any code. The first answer (suggesting Inkscape) worked perfectly for me!

Answer (score 3):

My attempt using [TikzEdt](http://www.tikzedt.org/index.html), a very useful tool for copy a figure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\definecolor{figBlue}{HTML}{080f6a}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
%frame
\filldraw [draw=figBlue,line width=9pt,fill=white](-12.5,-9.9) .. controls (-1.1,-14.3) 
and (0,-14.3) .. (0,-15.3) [rounded corners] .. controls (0,-14.3)
and (1.1,-14.3) .. (12.5,-9.9)[sharp corners]-- (12.5,15.2) -- (-12.5,15.2)[rounded corners]  -- cycle;
\path[tips,-{Computer Modern Rightarrow[figBlue,length=6ex,line width=1.5ex,sharp]}](0,0) to (0,-16.4);
%blue background circle
\fill[figBlue]  (0,1.7) circle (9.6);
%sun
\fill[white]  (0,7.4) circle (1.2);
%moon
\fill[white] (3.3,7.4) circle (1.3);
\fill [figBlue](3.7,8) circle (1.3);
%tail
\draw[white,line width=4.4pt,line cap=round]
(5.3,2.5)                  .. controls (5.6,2.7)
and (5.9,3)   .. (6,3.4)   .. controls (6,3.9)
and (5.8,4.1) .. (5.4,4.3) .. controls (5.1,4.4)
and (4.6,4.4) .. (4.1,4.3) .. controls (3.6,4.2)
and (3,4)     .. (2.5,3.9) .. controls (1.9,3.8)
and (1.4,3.8) .. (0.9,3.8) .. controls (0.6,3.8)
and (0.4,3.9) .. (0.1,4);
%body
\fill[white,thick] 
    (-5,-4.7) --  (-4.6,-4.3)
--  (-3.4,-0.1) .. controls (-3,2)
and (-3.9,3.6) .. (-4.3,4.8) .. controls (-4.4,5.4)
and (-4.9,5.2) .. (-5.1,5.1) .. controls (-5.2,5.1)
and (-5.3,5.1) .. (-5.4,5.2) .. controls (-5.4,5.3)
and (-5.3,5.3) .. (-5.2,5.4) .. controls (-5.2,5.4)
and (-5.1,5.5) .. (-5.2,5.5) .. controls (-5.3,5.5)
and (-5.6,5.6) .. (-5.7,5.6) .. controls (-5.8,5.7)
and (-5.6,5.8) .. (-5.5,5.9) .. controls (-5.4,6)
and (-4.7,6.2) .. (-4.5,6.3) .. controls (-4.4,6.5)
and (-4.6,6.6) .. (-4.7,6.8) .. controls (-4.7,7.3)
and (-4.3,7.7) .. (-4.2,7.9) .. controls (-4.2,7.5)
and (-4.3,7.1) .. (-4.2,6.6) .. controls (-4.1,6.5)
and (-3.9,6.5) .. (-3.7,6.5) .. controls (-3.4,7)
and (-3.6,7.4) .. (-3.6,7.6) .. controls (-3.6,7.8)
and (-3.5,7.9) .. (-3.3,7.6) .. controls (-3.2,7.4)
and (-3,7.1) ..   (-3.1,6.6) .. controls (-3.3,6.4)
and (-3,6.7) ..   (-3.4,6.3) .. controls (-3.5,6.2)
and (-3.4,6) ..   (-3.1,4.9) .. controls (-3,4.5)
and (-2.6,2.9) .. (-1.9,2.5) .. controls (-1.3,2.2)
and (-0.7,2.4) .. (0.5,2.6)  .. controls (1.4,2.8)
and (2.8,3) ..    (3.6,3)    .. controls (4.2,3)
and (5.3,3) ..    (5.5,2.3)  .. controls (5.7,1.6)
and (5.5,1.3) ..  (5,0.8)    .. controls (4.8,0.7)
and (4.8,0.5) ..  (4.8,0.2)
-- (5.3,-4.1) --  (5.4,-4.4)
-- (4.7,-4.4) --  (5,-4.1)
-- (4.2,-0.3) --  (2.9,-4.1)
-- (2.9,-4.4) --  (2.2,-4.4)
-- (2.5,-4.1) --  (3.5,-0.4) .. controls (3.6,-0.1)
and (3.6,0.1) ..  (3.6,0.5)  .. controls (3.6,1.3)
and (2.5,0.9) ..  (2,0.8)    .. controls (1,0.5)
and (-0.2,-0.1) ..(-2,0.2)
-- (-1.2,-4.7) -- (-1.5,-4.7)
-- (-1.9,-4.7) -- (-1.6,-4.4)
-- (-2.7,-0.2) -- (-4.3,-4.3)
-- (-4.3,-4.7) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image: logo created with TikZ and TikzEdt]

How I do this? 
I have import the figure in TikzEdt using `\node {\includegraphics{figure}};` and then I have copy the figure using the tools of TikzEdt. 
Obviously you should know pgf/Ti*k*Z for adjust the figure for the final result. For example in this figure I have added an arrow tip at the bottom of the frame.

Comment: Can you explain how you used `TikzEdt` to make this copy?

Comment: @AndréC You must import the figure in TikzEdt using `\node {\includegraphics{figure}};` and then copy the figure using the tools of TikzEdt. Obviously you should know pgf/TikZ for adjust the figure for the final result. For example in this figure I have add an arrow tip at the bottom of the frame.

Comment: Thank you. Can you update your answer with these explanations?